# Calcular valores de campo select de um formulário

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde a todos.

Preciso de uma ajuda de vocês. Tenho o seguinte select multiple:

```
    <select id="precoFruta" multiple name="valores">
        <option value="1.5">Macã - R$1,20</option>
        <option value="2.5">Uva  - R$2,50</option>
        <option value="1.0">Limão- R$1,00</option>            
    </select>
```

Conforme o usuario seleciona 1 ou mais frutas, fosse exibido um outro campo o resultado desta soma:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="valorTotal" name="valorTotal" value="" >
```

Como posso fazer isso com JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer essa forma:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
     $("#valorTotal").val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="precoFruta" multiple name="valores">
        <option value="1.5">Macã - R$1,20</option>
        <option value="2.5">Uva  - R$2,50</option>
        <option value="1.0">Limão- R$1,00</option>            
    </select>
    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valorTotal" name="valorTotal" value="" >
```

Pode rodar o código acima e ver o resultado.

Comment: ficou excelente... muito obrigada!!!

Comment: Oi @AmandaRJ tudo bem? Se resolveu o seu problema não deixa de marcar como resposta. Abs.

Comment: Resolveu sim, muito obrigada @Ricardo !

Answer (score 1):

Para obter todos as `option` selecionadas tens de percorrer uma a uma e ir buscar i seu valor.

Depois podes juntar tudo numa string para mostrar no input.

Podes fazer isso assim:

```
$('#precoFruta').on('change', function() {
    var values = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get().join(', ');
    $('#valorTotal').val(values);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ueoL007m/

```
Se for caso de quereres a soma deles podes fazer assim:

$('#precoFruta').on('change', function() {
    var soma = $(this).find('option:selected').get().reduce(function(sum, el) {
        return sum + Number(el.value);
    }, 0);
    $('#valorTotal').val(soma);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ueoL007m/1/

Comment: Obrigada @Sergio !